# How to connect to oracle database with both password and wallet?

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, windows-10, cx-oracle, wallet

I am using Oracle Client 18 Home 1 SQL Developer
platform is Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
python version is 3.8.8

cx_Oracle version is 8.0.1
cx_Oracle client version is (18, 3, 0, 0, 0)

I want to connect to Oracle database using cx_Oracle. My Oracle database is using 2 factor authentication, one is username and password, another one is wallet. So after research, I did the code below:

```
import cx_Oracle
import os
    
os.environ.get('ORACLE_HOME')
os.environ.get('TNS_ADMIN')
    
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='user', password='password', dsn='database_name')
```

I got error:
DatabaseError: ORA-28759: failure to open file

It works for my coworker but I don't know why it doesn't work for me.
Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: if you're using TNS_ADMIN, you need to be sure that you modified the sqlnet.ora file to put the proper path to the wallet.

Comment: I'm afraid there is nothing like 2FC auth in Oracle. Password being stored in wallet is something on client's side. The database does not know whether user entered the password of did withdraw it from a wallet.

Comment: path to the wallet is good. I am able to connect in SQL Developer

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/606

Answer (score 0):

I am not using Python, but similar error trying sqlplus to the database.

1. export TNS_ADMIN= -- like your did
2. Inside the sqlnet.ora file in that directory, make sure that the DIRECTORY points to the right directory.